# Dynamically output the page title with php

Tags: php, html

I am trying to output the page title dynamically. I am using induces and this script is withing the header.php the goal is to output the header dynamically using a case/switch statement. here is my code:

```
<?php  $title ;
    switch($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])  {
        case '/index.php': 
            $title = 'Home'; 
            break;
        case '/about.php': 
            $title = 'About'; 
            break;
        case '/services.php': 
            $title = 'Services'; 
            break;
        case '/portfolio.php': 
            $title = 'Portfolio'; 
            break;
        case '/staff.php': 
            $title = 'Staff'; 
            break;
        case '/contact.php': 
            $title = 'Contact us'; 
            break;
} ?>  <title><?php echo $title ?></title>
```

I am getting a error telling me my variable $title is not defined?

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: Provide a default value for title in switch case..

Comment: hey!!! check out my answer given below...it will solve your problem....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your first line, you have

```
<?php  $title ;
```

This `$title ;` shouldn't be there.

And, as Kailash Ahirwar already mentioned, it's always a good idea to provide a default value for your `$title`:

```
switch($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) {
    [...]
    default:
        $title = "Default title goes here";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to define `$title` before `switch`:

```
$title = "";
```

Answer (score 1):

in $_SERVER global array, $_SERVER[PHP_SELF] contains full path of file like

/project_name/index.php or /project_name/about.php or /project_name/services.php

Here project_name is name of your project.

replace

```
 case '/index.php'
 case '/about.php'
 case '/services.php'
 ....
```

to

```
 case '/project_name/index.php'
 case '/project_name/about.php'
 case '/project_name/services.php'
 .....
```

& also initialize $title in start of php file.

```
 <?php $title = ""; 

 switch ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) {
   case '/project_name/index.php':
     $title = 'Home'; 
     break;
  case '/project_name/about.php':
     $title = 'About';
     break;
  case '/project_name/services.php':
     $title = 'Services';
     break;
  case '/project_name/portfolio.php':
    $title = 'Portfolio';
    break;
 case '/project_name/staff.php':
    $title = 'Staff';
    break;
 case '/project_name/contact.php':
    $title = 'Contact us';
    break; 
 }
?>
```

for testing purposes

```
print_r($_SERVER);
```

and check for $_SERVER(PHP_SELF) value.

Comment: Note: `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` output starts with a `/`

Answer (score 0):

The code looks basically fine though you are missing a "default" block to catch anything that is not caught by any of the "case" statements.

Answer (score 0):

though a beginner in php, i sorted this out on my own, and it is very simple and logical, consider title as string and it is initially empty one write on top $title = "";
when including header in home page just after inclusion write the value of title(reassigning value of variable)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31838106)